# Vim equivalent of the "tr" command

Tags: vim

Have such line:

```
xxAyayyBwedCdweDmdwCkDwedBAwe
;;;; cleaner example
__A__B__C__D__C_D_BA_
```

want replace the `ABCD` into `PQRT` e.g. to get

```
__P__Q__R__T__R_T_QP_
```

e.g the quivalent of the next bash or perl `tr`

```
tr '[ABCD]' '[PQRT]' <<<"$string"
```

How to do this in "vim"? (VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May  9 2014 12:12:40))

Comment: is this cheating?  `%!tr 'ABCD' 'PQRT'`

Comment: @Kent heh... calling shell? it works, but have occasional problems with metacharacter escaping, especially when want `tr` the `[]` to `()` and such...

Comment: calling `!tr` is just for a short cmd. the `tr()` is better, particularly when `(external)tr` is not available.  however, with `!tr`, `() or [] ` won't be a problem. it is not regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `tr()` function combined with `:global`

```
:g/./call setline(line('.'), tr(getline('.'), 'ABCD', 'PQRS'))
```

It is easy to adapt it to a `:%Tr#ABCD#PQRS` command.

```
:command! -nargs=1 -range=1 Translate <line1>,<line2>call s:Translate(<f-args>)

function! s:Translate(repl_arg) range abort
  let sep = a:repl_arg[0]
  let fields = split(a:repl_arg, sep)
  " build the action to execute
  let cmd = a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'g'.sep.'.'.sep
        \. 'call setline(".", tr(getline("."), '.string(fields[0]).','.string(fields[1]).'))'
  " echom cmd
  " and run it
  exe cmd
endfunction
```

Comment: Great! For me enough the 1st line. :) Thanx a lot.

Comment: Nice. You don't need the `:g/./` BTW, as `:call` can take a range itself:.

Comment: Vimgolf: `%s/.*/\=tr(submatch(0), 'ABCD', 'PQRS')`

Comment: Golfier (assumes the cursor is in the first column): `C<C-r>=tr(@", 'ABCD', 'PQRS')<CR><Esc>`

Comment: @Jordan. I'd say _"different"_. Your solution only applies to the current line. Peter's and mine apply to any number of lines. They even leave `@"` unmodified -- which is something I appreciate in plugins. BTW, in order to alleviate the _on the first column_ constraint, you could use  `S` instead of `C`.

Comment: @LucHermitte All astute observations. Vim golf tends to be narrow in scope (the ability to e.g. give a range of lines is rarely needed) and lax about register pollution, and my comment was written in that spirit. Cheers!

Comment: Note to future me:  if you want to be prompted to confirm the replacement, but don't want to be asked on every single line, @PeterRincker's lovely [golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665318/vim-equivalent-of-the-tr-command#comment40112748_25665554) can be changed to `'a,'bs/[ABCD]\+/\=tr(submatch(0), 'ABCD', 'PQRS')/gc` (of course at the expense of being less golfy).