# Does Vim support character arithmetic?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to substitute `a` to `1` and `b` to `2` and so on. How can I achieve this process in vim regex?

e.g.:

```
disk1
disk2
disk3
...
```

=>

```
diska
diskb
diskc
...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "and so on"?

Comment: And in what scope? Whole file? One line? Current selection?...

Comment: Possible duplicate, but can't be sure due to vagueness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665318/vim-equivalent-of-the-tr-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
:s/2[0-6]\|1[0-9]\|[1-9]/\=nr2char(96+submatch(0))/
```

It will look for numbers `1-26` and replace them by letters `a-z`. You'll have to specify a range yourself; as-is it will perform one substitution on one line only. (Try `:%s/.../.../g` to perform multiple substitutions per line, in the whole file.)

Comment: If the regex match is a letter and you want to "increase" it, you may need to add `char2nr(submatch(0))` to convert the letter into its code number before before performing calculations on it.

Answer (score 0):

@Mauris answer pretty much explains what you need, but in case you want to increase/decrease a number you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>x</kbd>. This should work for both numbers and letters, but in case it doesn't work for letters: use `set nrformats+=alpha`

For such case you can use it in a macro.